# Is possible to get all post metadata that themes can add

Tags: posts

When i activate theme, theme adds new fields to post page. For example "***news source***". Is possible to get list of fields which theme added to post page?

With "***get_post_meta***", i can reach metadata for existing post. If "***news source***" filed was empty, "***get_post_meta***" doesn't show "***news source***" in results.

Comment: WP doesn't store a "list of all possible postmeta" anywhere, so no, there's no place to access it. You'll want to search through the theme files to find all possibilities. Or, you could create a new test post and fill out all the fields, then pull its postmeta, to get a list - though you'd want to be sure that the theme is adding this postmeta to all post types. It's possible it's different for every post type.

Comment: Thaks. But, Maybe wordpress refers a standard theme file  to create post adding form. If so i can analyze this theme file for all themes to get list of possible metadata.

Comment: You could check `functions.php` but that's not the only place it can be added. Always safest to check all the files.

Comment: And don't forget, plugins can add postmeta as well.